How to catch printing errors from background thread in Elmish/F#
I have a print function in F# that uses an STA thread:
let PrintProgressNoteAsync (encounterid:int)  = 
              async {
                    let mutable printmsg = null
                    let thread = Thread(fun () -> printmsg <- PrintProgressNote encounterid);
                    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
                    thread.Start(); 
                    thread.Join(); 
                    return printmsg
              }

Upon successful printing, PrintProgressNote, returns a string:
sprintf "Progress note printed to %s" printername

However, printing is prone to failure. How can a printer error within "PrintProgressNote" from a background thread be marshalled up the line to be ultimately caught and handled by
Elmish?
i.e., (in Elmish), I need Cmd.Async.either Print encounterid OnPrintSuccess OnPrintError
to receive a string OnPrintSuccess and exn OnPrintError.
Thank you for your consideration.

Wrap printing in try..with?

@FyodorSoikin try..with will catch the errors--but then how to send them to Elmish's OnPrintError. I have a complete missing link here (and can't find any documentation). :(

Return the error same way you're returning printmsg

Finally made this work. I'd sure appreciate a better answer though. Essentially, the code that crashes is responsible for returning the appropriate choice which is then passed upward to its caller. Elmish then catches the error where it is shown to the user. Here is the working code.
Important! -- when run in Visual Studio, must start without debugging or the debugger will catch the error immediately and not send it upward.
let PrintProgressNote (encounterid:int)  =
            try
                // code to print...
                Choice1Of2 (sprintf "Progress note printed to %s" printername)
            with
            |exn -> Choice2Of2 exn 

let printProgressNoteAsync (encounterid:int)   = 
             async {
                    let mutable printmsg = Choice1Of2 ""
                    let thread = Thread(fun () -> printmsg <- PrintProgressNote encounterid)

                    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
                    thread.Start(); 
                    thread.Join();         
                    return printmsg
              } 

let PrintProgressNoteAsync (encounterid:int)  = 
            async {
                    let! r = printProgressNoteAsync encounterid 
                    match r with
                    |Choice1Of2 s -> return s
                    |Choice2Of2 e -> raise e ; return "Error"
            }

